# Data Loader - Automated way to import data with parameters from Command Line

Tags: data-loader

Can we automate the process of a data import operation with the following conditions ?

-> The .csv file containing the data to be imported is present in the particular folder.

-> The custom object (target object of data import) has 5 fields. 4 fields' data is available in the .csv. The fifth field should be set by the data loader itself. It is not a formula field. The fifth field will contain a string data of a Case number.

->The fifth field will be sent as one of the parameters during the batch file invocation.

Comment: So the dataloader should be adding a column? I'm not sure it can do that but an etl tool like talend can.

Comment: tx..cannot we default the fifth's field value in the .sdl file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dataloader itself cannot modify the data in the csv. However, a shell script (batch file in Windows) can modify the csv before it is passed to the dataloader for loading.

Comment: tx..cannot we default the fifth's field value in the .sdl file ?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

For Automating the apex data loader through command line  refer the following liks.....

It might be useful for your scenario....

http://www.sundoginteractive.com/sunblog/posts/automating-the-apex-data-loader

http://gaganbansalblog4u.com/2013/08/11/cli-data-loader-through-command-prompt-salesforce/